# How to prevent multiple alert rendering using react native?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In my case, I am using `alert component` in render part, while I am executing app due to `multiple time rendering` my alert also calling twice and moretime. I have to `prevent` it, when alert is already displaying.

My Code Here:

```
return (    
      { alert rendering condition (
        <AlertPack
          title= ""
          subTitle=""
          alertButtons={[
            {
              text: "ok",
              onPress: () => {....}
            },
            {
              text: "cancel",
              onPress: () => {....},
            },
          ]} 
        />
      )}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Showing `Alert` on rendering view is not the best practice. Best way to show an alert when some condition gets true on some action like Button press or initially on screen mount.

For now, you can do some workaround like

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showAlert: false, // default false so don't show
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: true, // reset state on your condition to show alert. I've done on screen mount
    })
  }

  render() {

    { this.state.showAlert ? (
        <AlertPack
          title= ""
          subTitle=""
          alertButtons={[
            {
              text: "ok",
              onPress: () => {....}
            },
            {
              text: "cancel",
              onPress: () => {....},
            },
          ]} 
        />
      ) : null }
  }
```

Comment: Yes I agree. As of now we have to provide quick solution without changing much code. Kindly please tell me how to prevent.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check and update it

Comment: is there any alternative?

Comment: @Devapp I have updated my answer please check

Comment: it is not working. Can I create it as a separate function, even that also not working

Answer (score 0):

It is not best practice but you can use another parameter whether you showed alert or not and useEffect to change that parameter. You also need to change your condition as;

`alertCondition && !alerted`

```
    const [alertCondition, setAlertCondition] = useState(false);
    const [alerted, setAlerted] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        if(alertCondition)
            setAlerted(true);
        else
            setAlerted(false);
    }, [alertCondition]);
```

Comment: Thank you I will check

Comment: can you please update your code without useEffects. I am using class component.